# Gmail Showing "Updates" in "Primary" Tab

Tags: gmail, gmail-categories

I'm using the Gmail categories setup with Primary/Promotions/Social/Updates all enabled. I previously was only using Primary, Promotions, and Social, but since I enabled "Updates" a couple weeks ago, I'm having a weird issue.

Emails are properly tagged by Gmail and everything looks right when I first load the inbox, but after clicking into an email and then back to the inbox, all of the "Updates" also show up in "Primary".

This only happens with Updates (social and promotions still only show in their tabs) and the Updates still show up in the Updates tab, it's just that they also flood the Primary tab (thereby ruining the usefulness of it).

Comment: Are the messages `starred` ?

Comment: @BlindSpots no they are not starred. and it's not that just some messages are showing up where they shouldn't, ALL of the "Updates" are showing improperly in Primary

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by changing the "Filtered mail" setting in "Inbox" tab. Previously the "Override filters" option was checked. After I changed it to "Don't override filters" everything seems to work as expected.

But I assume now there's a possibility that it will filter some important emails into the "Updates" category. Gonna monitor it's behavior for a couple of weeks to be sure everything is fine.

Hope this helps.

[image: Gmail Inbox Settings]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Disable "Updates" and save the settings. Go to the settings again and enable it once again then save. This should refresh the settings from the rerouting hiccup.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion but tried this earlier and it didn't work. Just tried again and even included logging out and back in and enabling/disabling other tabs too and still nothing.

Answer (score -1):

I had to leave Updates disabled. If I enable it again the emails go there again. But disabling "Updates" does fix the problem.